# Using Mysql GROUP_CONCAT in JOIN Query

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a string resulting like this :

```
'41,42,43,44,45,46,'
```

from this query :

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(lv
        SEPARATOR ',') as Id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @pv:=(SELECT 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(Id
                            SEPARATOR ',')
                FROM
                    iot_zone
                WHERE
                    FIND_IN_SET(id_zone, @pv)) AS lv
    FROM
        iot_zone
    JOIN (SELECT @pv:=40) tmp) a;
```

I need to join this result to a query like :

```
SELECT T.* FROM T, T2
WHERE T.Id = T2.Id
```

where T2 is a table with the result of GROUP_CONCAT

```
41
42
43
44
45
46
```

Can you help me ?

Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but instead of using `GROUP_CONCAT` to aggregate a list of values into a string, why not leave the values as denormalized rows where you can easily join them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
CREATE TABLE T2(Id int);
INSERT T2(Id)VALUES(41),(42),(43);

SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT '41,42,43,44,45,46,' Id
  ) T
JOIN T2 on CONCAT(',',T.Id) LIKE CONCAT('%,',T2.Id,',%')
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

I found another variant with `FIND_IN_SET` - [SELECT WHERE IN with GROUP_CONCAT as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689406/select-where-in-with-group-concat-as-input/47690221)

I think it'll be more useful

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT '41,42,43,44,45,46,' IdList
  ) T
JOIN T2 ON FIND_IN_SET(T2.Id,T.IdList)
```

Comment: I found another very good variant for MySQL with `FIND_IN_SET`. I added it into my answer, too.